# Brief explanation of some input/outputs of RISC-V Core

Tags: caching, fetch, verilog, cpu, riscv

I am trying to analyze the code of fetch.v file from (https://github.com/ultraembedded/riscv/tree/master/core/riscv), but the designer has no documentation explaining anything and I am very beginner at the world of Verilog and digital design. What do these mean and do ?

```
,input           fetch_accept_i
,input           icache_accept_i
,input           icache_valid_i
,input           icache_error_i
,input  [ 31:0]  icache_inst_i
,input           icache_page_fault_i
,input           fetch_invalidate_i
,input           branch_request_i
,input  [ 31:0]  branch_pc_i
,input  [  1:0]  branch_priv_i

// Outputs
,output          fetch_valid_o
,output [ 31:0]  fetch_instr_o
,output [ 31:0]  fetch_pc_o
,output          fetch_fault_fetch_o
,output          fetch_fault_page_o
,output          icache_rd_o
,output          icache_flush_o
,output          icache_invalidate_o
,output [ 31:0]  icache_pc_o
,output [  1:0]  icache_priv_o
,output          squash_decode_o
```

The design is very complex. I wish there is a good resource I could read to understand his design

Answer (score 0):

This is a file that describe the fetch unit of the core.
input means that's a input wire of the unit and output an output one.

The goal of this stage is to fetch instructions from the cache/memory and to send it to the decod unit.

Problem is that every implementation is different but basically :

```
,input           fetch_accept_i : fetch is accepted by fetch stage (signal come from decode)
,input           icache_accept_i : instruction cache accept the request from fetch unit
,input           icache_valid_i : icache answer is valid
,input           icache_error_i : icache answer made an error
,input  [ 31:0]  icache_inst_i : instruction fetch by the cache
,input           icache_page_fault_i : cache did a page fault exception\ 
,input           fetch_invalidate_i : fetch was invalid
,input           branch_request_i : fetch unit made a branch request
,input  [ 31:0]  branch_pc_i : branch address of pc 
,input  [  1:0]  branch_priv_i : current priviledge of the core (M, S or U)

// Outputs
,output          fetch_valid_o : fetch request is valid
,output [ 31:0]  fetch_instr_o : ?
,output [ 31:0]  fetch_pc_o : current pc which is fetch
,output          fetch_fault_fetch_o : fetch did a fault
,output          fetch_fault_page_o : fault did a page fault
,output          icache_rd_o : ?
,output          icache_flush_o : flush request to the cache
,output          icache_invalidate_o : invalidate request to the cache
,output [ 31:0]  icache_pc_o : current pc 
,output [  1:0]  icache_priv_o : priviledge mode
,output          squash_decode_o : ?
```

I'm not sure with my answer but according to the name of the signal i can do these assumptions

Comment: I pretty much got the purpose of the fetch design, the big picture exactly as you said, but then these I/O's are left without simple comments to indicate their function unfortunately

Comment: I answered in a new post cause comment accept few characters

Comment: You should normally [edit] your existing answer to add more detail. Only post a separate answer if your existing answer is already detailed about one thing, and you want to post a totally different answer that readers might want to vote on separately.  And/or if you're getting close to the 30k character limit for a single answer, but normally it's best to fit everything into one answer post.

Comment: Right, I'll do so thanks